# Connecting to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I'm VS2005 installed with SQL Server.

How can I use it to connect SQL Server 2005 and create new database?  Am I missing SQL Server 2005's Management Studio to be able to make database queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can do most of the database development tasks that you'd ever want to do without having to use Management Studio.

Here's an article describing how to connect to your database in Server Explorer: [How to use the Server Explorer in Visual Studio .NET and Visual Studio 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316649)

Here's [what to do](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/f7c2f8c6-1450-434f-af05-2c584e7ff790/) if you don't see Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

And **here's a video to get you started**: [How to Use the Server Explorer in MS Visual Studio 2005](http://www.5min.com/Video/How-to-Use-the-Server-Explorer-in-MS-Visual-Studio-2005-85453976)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Server Explorer` window in Visual Studio. It's capable of connecting to sql server instances and do most of the db management tasks.